# Configure DataSource Using JNDI Using external Tomcat 9 Server: Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jndi, tomcat9

I have a SpringBootApplication, packaged as war file:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

on the application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/bonanza
```

but on the logs I see those messages when I deploy the war in the Tomcat 9:

```
Name [spring.datasource.jndi-name] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.datasource.jndi-name].. Returning null.
```

the logs:

```
12:37:53.989 [main] DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/spring.datasource.jndi-name]
12:37:53.989 [main] DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/spring.datasource.jndi-name] not found - trying original name [spring.datasource.jndi-name]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [spring.datasource.jndi-name] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.datasource.jndi-name].
12:37:53.990 [main] DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [spring.datasource.jndi-name]
12:37:53.991 [main] DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [spring.datasource.jndi-name] threw NamingException with message: Name [spring.datasource.jndi-name] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.datasource.jndi-name].. Returning null.
12:37:53.995 [main] DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/spring.datasource.jndi-name]
12:37:53.996 [main] DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/spring.datasource.jndi-name] not found - trying original name [spring.datasource.jndi-name]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [spring.datasource.jndi-name] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.datasource.jndi-name].
12:37:53.996 [main] DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [spring.datasource.jndi-name]
12:37:53.997 [main] DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [spring.datasource.jndi-name] threw NamingException with message: Name [spring.datasource.jndi-name] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.datasource.jndi-name].. Returning null.
12:37:53.998 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'spring.datasource.jndi-name' in PropertySource 'configurationProperties' with value of type String
```

on my `tomcat9/conf/context.xml:`

```
 <Resource  name="jdbc/bonanza" 
                auth="Container" 
                type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                maxTotal="100" 
                maxIdle="30" 
                maxWaitMillis="10000"
                username="a_usr" 
                password="Mu*7gydlcdstg100@" 
                driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                url="jdbc:mysql://172.175.77.55:3306/a_db"
        />
```

Comment: are you using an embedded tomcat server or external tomcat?

Comment: external tomcat, sir

Comment: I have made some change in the answer below you can try it out.

Comment: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, spring boot cannot find the key in the JNDI lookup. JNDI is disabled in Spring boot's embedded Tomcat so you would need to enable it using `Tomcat#enableNaming` and once that is done you would need to create a lookup entry in JNDI. You can refer to the below code which I copied from one of the spring boot project  maintainers repository [GitHub repo JNDI-Tomcat](https://github.com/wilkinsona/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-jndi/blob/master/src/main/java/sample/tomcat/jndi/SampleTomcatJndiApplication.java)

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

        @Override
        protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(
                Tomcat tomcat) {
            tomcat.enableNaming();
            return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
        }

        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            ContextResource resource = new ContextResource();
            resource.setName("jdbc/bonanza");
            resource.setType(DataSource.class.getName());
            resource.setProperty("driverClassName", "your.db.Driver");
            resource.setProperty("url", "jdbc:yourDb");

            context.getNamingResources().addResource(resource);
        }
    };
}
```

**[Edit]**

As you are not using embedded tomcat server, you can configure JNDI by configuring it using tomcat config files:

In server.xml, create a Resource under `<GlobalNamingResources>`

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="..." 
                           maxActive="..." 
                           maxIdle="..." 
                           maxWait="..." 
                           name="jdbc/bonanza"  
                           username="..."
                           password="..."
                           type="..."
                           url="..."/>
```

In Context.xml, you can link the resource

```
<context>
    <ResourceLink auth="Container" name="jdbc/bonanza" global="jdbc/bonanza" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</context>
```

Also, make sure you are not starting the application using the spring-boot `main` method. You need to build the war file using maven/gradle and then deploy it to the tomcat and test it.

Comment: I did it with the same result, sir :-(

Comment: @NuñitodelaCalzada what was the issue? I am suspecting you were testing using spring-boot `main` method instead of deploying the war. is that so?

Comment: indeed, it was so :-)